# Can NSUserDefault be overwritten?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

There's a NSUserDefault with Value:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"aValue"];`

Can it be overwritten by the another value? As:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"2" forKey:@"aValue"];`

If yes what may be the pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the value will be overwritten. NSUserDefaults is used to store information even after your app is closed.

This is often desired when you want to (for example in a game) increase the number of levels the user has completed.

The only disadvantage I see is that if you forget the name of a key, you might accidentally write over the value already there when you didn't intend to.

Comment: I've taken to creating constant strings in my classes that use the defaults. Then the string name will fill in with autocomplete. It makes things much easier to remember.

Comment: I too do this. I define all of my keys as `#define KEYS_SOME_VALUE @"keyvalue"` then I get a autocomplete list of all possible keys when I type `KEYS`